# How to escape Perl regular expression characters in array and in grep?

Tags: arrays, regex, perl

I have two questions but also could be so easy to answer. Probably just a newbie questions. There is little about this on Google.

First: How do you put Perl matching operators in array?
For example all of these characters:

```
{}[]()^$.|*+?\
```

to use then with foreach?

Second, if you have this:

```
@array = qw(The $ quick ? brown | fox jumps over the lazy dog);

$string = "\? brown \|";

@new_array = grep(/$string/,@array);
```

How to properly find $string in the @array if @array is some text for example which contains dollar sign, question mark etc.? If you search regex character it will turn into operator. And if you do this:

```
$string =~ s/\$/\$/gi;
```

it will have the same result of course.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you want to match a regex against an array? Your example seems to suggest you don't want to match each element, but somehow groups of neighbouring elements. What's the expected output of `grep /$string/, @array`?

Comment: Yes, I want to match a dollar sign as a dollar, not a regular expression character

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that this:

```
$string = "\? brown \|";
```

is just a misleading way to write this:

```
$string = "? brown |";
```

The best fix is either (option 1) not to use a string at all, but a pattern object:

```
$pat = qr/\? brown \|/;

@new_array = grep(/$pat/,@array);
```

or (2) to use `\Q` to "quote" any regex metacharacters in the string when you create the pattern:

```
$string = "? brown |";

@new_array = grep(/\Q$string/,@array);
```

Failing that, you can ensure that your string ends up actually containing `\? brown \|` (instead of just `? brown |`) by writing any of these:

```
$string = "\\? brown \\|"; # option 3
$string = '\? brown \|';   # option 4
$string = "\Q\? brown \|"; # option 5
```

Comment: This was the answer I was searching for in searching array with regex characters. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The strings to search for a match don't need special care or escaping, apart from suitable quoting. The matching patterns need be escaped if they are to match literally, and this needs to be protected from interpolation if there is extra quoting. See the end for a comment on quoting. For example

```
my @spec_ch = qw({ } [ ] ( ) ^ $ . | * + ? \ ); 
my @matched = grep { /\$|\?/ } @spec_ch;
print "@matched\n";
```

Prints

```
$ ?
```

---

**Your actual example**, only shortened and with `foreach` (see below for comment on `grep`).

```
my @patterns = ('\?', 'brown', '\|', 'fox');  # or  qw(\? brown \| fox); 
my $string   = '? brown |';                   # or   q(? brown |);
foreach my $patt (@patterns) {
    my ($match) = $string =~ /($patt)/;
    print "$match\n" if $match;
}
```

Prints

```
?
brown
|
```

---

Your example turned around, so to use a pattern with both words and escaped characters

```
my $str = q(The $ quick ? brown | fox jumps over the lazy dog);
my $patt = qr(\? brown \|);  # or simply '\? brown \|'
my ($match) = $str =~ /($patt)/;
print "$match\n" if $match;
```

Prints

```
? brown |
```

---

**The problem with your** `grep` **example** is that it attempts to match the other way around -- variable `$string` is used as a pattern, while words from the array as strings to search for match.

```
grep { $_ =~ /$string/ } @array; 
# regex syntax: $text =~ /$pattern/, so above $_ is string, $string is pattern
```

So `$_` takes on values `The`, `$`, `quick` (etc) in turn, and they are searched for the pattern `$string` *inside* of them. The `foreach` example above does what you probably had in mind.

---

The double quotes may pose problems since they interpolate and then you have to do additional escaping. Use single quotes and then the escaped special characters inside are carried that way into the regex, without any interpretation.

The operators `qw` and `q` do not interpolate. See [Quote and Quote-like Operators in perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators).